# Why isn't the table being created from within the stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am creating stored procedure in which I need to build a temporary table dynamically. I tried the following code but its not creating table. When I execute the generated Query in Query window it works fine there.

```
--declare query variable
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(MAX)
SET @Query = 'CREATE TABLE #final (DATE int,'   


--DECLARE @COLUMNNAME VARIABLE
DECLARE @ColName nvarchar(10)

OPEN @taCur

FETCH NEXT FROM @taCur INTO @ColName
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Query = @Query + 'T_' + @ColName +' int,'   
    FETCH NEXT FROM @taCur INTO @ColName
END

SET @Query = @Query + 'TOTAL int,CUMM_TOTAL int)'
print @Query
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
--SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO #final (DATE) VALUES (1)'
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM #final'
print @Query
EXEC(@Query)
```

Final generated create table Query is as follow

```
CREATE TABLE #final (DATE int,T_211E int,T_211G int,T_211H int,T_211J int,T_211L int,T_221F int,TOTAL int,CUMM_TOTAL int)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object *#final* used in *CREATE* and *SELECT* statements is not in the same scope.

Here is one way to structure the query.

- Try to terminate SQL statements with semicolon. Even though it is not mandatory, it will help you differentiate the statements for readability. Note that I have included semicolon at the end of *CREATE*, *INSERT* and *SELECT* statements.
- You can notice that *CREATE*, *INSERT* and *SELECT* are executed in the same transaction. Thereby, you don't lose the scope of the temporary table.

*Script*:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.ColumnSchema
    (
        ColName NVARCHAR(10)
    );

    INSERT INTO dbo.ColumnSchema (ColName) VALUES
        ('211E'),
        ('211G'),
        ('211H'),
        ('211J'),
        ('211L'),
        ('211F');


DECLARE @Query      NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ColName    NVARCHAR(10);

SET @Query = 'CREATE TABLE #final (DATE int,';

DECLARE taCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT  ColName
    FROM    dbo.ColumnSchema;

OPEN taCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM taCursor 
    INTO @ColName

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

        SET @Query = @Query + 'T_' + @ColName + ' int, '   

        FETCH NEXT FROM taCursor 
            INTO @ColName
    END

CLOSE       taCursor;
DEALLOCATE  taCursor;

SET @Query = @Query + 'TOTAL int,CUMM_TOTAL int); '
SET @Query = @Query + 'INSERT INTO #final (DATE) VALUES (1); '
SET @Query = @Query + 'SELECT * FROM #final; '

EXEC (@Query);
```

*Output*:

```
DATE T_211E T_211G T_211H T_211J T_211L T_211F TOTAL CUMM_TOTAL
---- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ----- ----------
1    NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL   NULL  NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @Siva...your answer is much helpful

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your temp table only exists within the scope that it is created... which is within the scope of your first `sp_executesql`.  When you call your `select` statement, your temp table is no longer in scope.

To fix this, you would have to build up a single string that contains everything you need to do with your temp table: your `create`, `insert`, and `select` all within the a single `sp_executesql` call.

However, you should be aware that your current approach is likely vulnerable to SQL injection if you don't have complete control over all the values that are used to build up your commands.

Comment: what should I do to get select statement in scope ??